# Insert Instruction in basicblock llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

In the following code, I am trying to insertnew global variables in .ll file using Module Pass:

```
Module::FunctionListType &FList= M.getFunctionList();
LLVMContext &Ctx= M.getContext();
int x=0;
std::string Cbb="BB";
GlobalVariable *bbcounter;

for (Module::FunctionListType::iterator fit=FList.begin();fit!=FList.end();fit++){

   for (Function::iterator b = (*fit).begin(), be = (*fit).end(); b != be; ++b){

      Cbb= "BB"+std::to_string(x);
      const Twine &tw(Cbb);
      b->setName (tw);
      bbcounter=new GlobalVariable(M,Type::getInt64Ty(b->getContext()),false,GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage,0,Cbb);
      assert(bbcounter&&"Error: unable to get basicblock counter");
      x++;
}}
```

The following one is for inserting load/store if the new global variables:

```
for (Module::FunctionListType::iterator fit=FList.begin();fit!=FList.end();fit++)
{

Function::iterator b = (*fit).begin();
Function::iterator be = (*fit).end();

for ( ; b != be; ++b, git++){      //git is global variable

Instruction *InsertPos=b->getTerminator();
LoadInst* OldVal=new LoadInst( &(*git), Cbb);
OldVal->insertBefore (InsertPos);
Instruction * NewVal= BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, OldVal, ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt64Ty(b->getContext()), 1), Cbb);
NewVal->insertBefore (InsertPos);
StoreInst *SI=new StoreInst(NewVal, &*git);
SI->insertBefore (InsertPos);
}
```

This code after make and call opt command does not edit anything in .ll file. I there a problem in it? or should I write new file ?

Note: I tried to write a new file using removeFromParent() function, but it gives me errors. Also, cloning does not set right predecessors.

Comment: Do you save your module? If yes, it is saved in binary format, so you need `llvm-dis` to decompile it to textual representation.

Comment: Do you mean by saving module to write the module into a new file?

Comment: I saved the module to new file (ir). When I run lli file.ll, it gives me this error "LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'BB11' which could not be resolved!"

Comment: Also, I used llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile and gives me the same error

Comment: BB11 is a global variable